# Read text file into matrix python

Tags: python, removing-whitespace

I want to read a text file that has trailing white spaces:

```
0 3 4 5 2 
3 0 2 4 0 
4 2 0 1 0 
5 4 1 0 0 
2 0 0 0 0
```

into a matrix like so:

```
[[0, 3, 4, 5, 2], [3, 0, 2, 4, 0], [4, 2, 0, 1, 0], [5, 4, 1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as filename:
   adjmtrx = [[int(num) for num in line.split(' ')] for line in filename if line.rstrip('')]
```

But I get the following error:

```
adjmtrx = [[int(num) for num in line.split(' ')] for line in filename if line.strip() != " "]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'
```

I think I'm close..

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me. I get that error if I add two new lines at the end of the file which contains the matrix, so the problem must be in the data file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to strip where you are using the value.

`if line.rstrip('')` does not do what you think it does. Read up more on [.strip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip).

```
with open(filename, 'r') as filename:
   adjmtrx = [[int(num) for num in line.strip().split(' ')] for line in filename]

print(adjmtrx)
# [[0, 3, 4, 5, 2], [3, 0, 2, 4, 0], [4, 2, 0, 1, 0], [5, 4, 1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: No, the `if line.rstrip('')` test is intentional, I'm pretty sure. Using this allows the code to skip blank lines in the input.

Comment: Okay, agreed. Anyways the check is harmless, can be kept. @KarlKnechtel

Answer (score 0):

The `line.rstrip()` returns the same text without spaces on the right. You can use that to remove whitespaces on right. You can use `split()` for converting a line to a list (the default argument of it is `" "`).

```py
def read_file(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as filename:
        l = []
        for i in filename.readlines():
            l.append([int(ii) for ii in i.rstrip().split()])
        return l

print(read_file("filename.txt"))
```